# How do you get number frequencies in a list, then index into another list?

Tags: python

Python 2.7.5 (Don't judge me)

What I have (e.g.):

```
numbers = [1,3,5,1,3,5,7,0,2,2,9,1]

frequencies = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I need a *for loop* that counts by going through the elements of **numbers** and modifying **frequencies** accordingly by indexing. **frequencies** should look like:

```
[1,3,2,2,0,2,0,1,0,1]
```

I tried using the len() function...for some reason...I just haven't found a way to incorporate count properly.

Comment: Show what have you already tried.

Comment: I honestly don't know what is being asked here, and can see no relation between the given lists and the expected result.

Comment: and there is nothing wrong with 2.7

Comment: I tried for i in numbers: frequencies[0] = numbers [len('0')]. I apologize for any confusion. I'm a beginner...as you can tell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for n in numbers:
    frequencies[n] += 1
```

Comment: Yeah, that's embarrassing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that every element of numbers is between 0 and the length of frequencies, inclusive-exclusive:

```
for i in range(len(frequencies)):
    frequencies[i] = numbers.count(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Counter works great for this.

```
from collections import Counter

numbers = [1,3,5,1,3,5,7,0,2,2,9,1]
freq = Counter(numbers)
# Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2, 5: 2, 0: 1, 7: 1, 9: 1})

# dictionary
d = dict(freq)
#{0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2, 5: 2, 7: 1, 9: 1}

# tuples
t = freq.items()
# [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2), (5, 2), (7, 1), (9, 1)]

# list
L = [freq[n] for n in xrange(max(freq.keys()) + 1)]
# [1, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1]

# add more
freq.update(numbers)
# Counter({1: 6, 2: 4, 3: 4, 5: 4, 0: 2, 7: 2, 9: 2})
```

[collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)